# Подсчёт четных элементов в строке двумерного массива

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть вот такой двумерный массив

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как посчитать количество четных по значению элементов каждой строки, а также найти номер строки массива с наибольшим количеством четных элементов и вывести эту строчку отдельно?

Comment: количество четных построчно: 4, 4, 4, 5

Comment: отдельно номер строки с наибольшим количеством четных чисел: 4

Comment: _Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;

namespace stack_over_2
{
    internal class Program
    {

        static int[,] Filling(int x, int y)
        {
            var rund = new Random();
            var result = new int[x, y];

            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                {
                    result[i, j] = rund.Next(0, 100);
                    Console.Write(String.Format("{0,3}", result[i, j]));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            return result;
        }

        static void Solve(int[,] array)
        {
            int max_value = 0, temp_item = 0, max_line = 0, same_line = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                temp_item = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if ((array[i, j] & 1) == 0)
                        temp_item++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"В {i+1} строке {temp_item} чисел");

                if (temp_item >= max_value)
                {
                    max_line = i;
                    max_value = temp_item;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"\nСтрока с максимальным количеством четных чисел {max_line+1}\n" +
                $"Всего в ней {max_value} четных чисел");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] array = Filling(4 ,5);
            Solve(array);

        }
    }
}
```

Если понравился ответ засчитаете его

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]